# Need to put validation on files before AzCopy delete executes

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

AzcopyVersion 10.4.3 ; Operating system: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, 64 bit. I am trying to put validation check only copied files to be deleted in Azure

```
file_filter *.txt;*.dat

azcopy copy !azure_server!/container/!azure_key! !local_destination_path! --include-pattern="!file_filter!" --recursive=true
azcopy rm !azure_server!/container/!azure_key! --include-pattern="!file_filter!" --recursive=true
```

1. Copy files from blob with file pattern matches
2. Delete the files from blob with file pattern matches but I need to have validation check in place AzCopy rm deletes only copies files not randomly by pattern. Please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: What is your vesion of AzCopy, and your operating system?

Comment: AzcopyVersion  10.4.3
Operating system: windows server 2019 Datacenter, 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

> Need to put validation on files before AzCopy delete executes

To validate only copied files are deleted in `Azure` using `AzCopy`, you can follow the below steps.

1. Copy only `* .txt` and `*.dat` files from the blob storage to your local destination using `AzCopy` with the `--include-pattern`

```
azcopy copy https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/test/containername "local destination path" --include-pattern="*.txt;*.dat" --recursive=true
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once you have copied the `*.txt` and `*.dat` files from the storage account to local, you can perform the validation by comparing the list of copied files with the files you intended to copy.

```
$copiedFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "/home/xdv/" -File -Recurse -Include *.txt, *.dat | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once you have the list of copied files, you can use `AzCopy` again with the `--include-pattern` option to delete only the files that were successfully copied.

```
azcopy rm "https://storageaccount name.blob.core.windows.net/test/<sastoken>" --include-pattern="*.txt;*.dat" --recursive=true
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This will not solve my problem, our script is scheduled, let me elaborate the issue which i am facing the user is sending files on every 5 mins to blob at same time our script is trying perform above copy & rm commands at first instanse copy was not happened because user's send file is still writing into blob after when delete command execution starts it got deleted so now i need auotmatic solution to modify script which need to do 1) copy files to local/temporary location
2) compare copied files from local and blob 
3) if both are matching then perform delete/remove operation.

Comment: ex: ABC_20230629_122.dat, ABC_20230629_123.dat, ABC_20230629_124.dat
issues happened: 122,123 copied when delete command executed 122,123,124 also got deleted from blob

Comment: Can any one help my request?

Comment: Please help me the request

Comment: If the file type matches *.txt and *.dat, regardless of the file's content.